# C# лямбда-выражение при работе со строкой

Tags: c#, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Есть стандартый вариант функции, для поиска ошибки в коде Хэминга

```
static int FindMistake(string str)
    {
        var mistake = 0;
        
        foreach (var i in str)
        {
            if (i == '1') mistake ^= i + 1;
        }

        return mistake;
    }
```

Как переписать это, используя лямбда-выражения?
Поиск в интернете приводит к решениям, которые используют List, но не string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка итерируется точно так же как массив символов `char[]`, вы же сами по ней `foreach` запускаете. Никакой разницы в этом случае между строкой, массивом или списком нет.

Странный код, почему `i + 1`? ведь если брать `'1'` то получится код символа + 1, то есть `mistake ^= 50` так как код символа 1 равен 49. Ну либо в показанном коде ошибка.

Ну ок, не влезая в подробности, то если количество вхождений четное, то функция вернет 0, если нечетное, то 50, окей.

```
static int FindMistake(string str) => (str.Count(x => x == '1') % 2) * 50;
```

Только вы не лямбда-выражение хотели, а Linq, я полагаю. Но можно не `int` а `bool` возвращать, типа есть/нет.

```
static bool FindMistake(string str) => str.Count(x => x == '1') % 2 != 0;
```